# How to remove punctuation from a txt (inaugural)?

Tags: python

The code below manages to remove all the stopwords from the txt in inaugural but my only problem is that I also need to remove punctuation from the list. Any help on how I can do this.

```
def content_text(inaugural):
    stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words('english'))
    w_stp = Counter()
    wo_stp  = Counter()
    for word in inaugural:

        word = word.lower()
        if word in stopwords:
             w_stp.update([word])
        else:

            wo_stp.update([word])

    return [k for k,_ in w_stp.most_common(10)],[y for y,_ in wo_stp.most_common(10)]

print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('1861-Lincoln.txt', )))
print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('1941-Roosevelt.txt', )))
print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('1945-Roosevelt.txt', )))
print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('1981-Reagan.txt', )))
print(content_text(nltk.corpus.inaugural.words('1985-Reagan.txt', )))
```

Comment: do you have comprehensive list of punctuation or just `!"#$%&\'()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^_`{|}~` will do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

how about this:

```
for word in inaugural:

    word = word.lower().replace(',', '').replace(';','').replace('.',''))
    if len(word.strip()) > 0:
        if word in stopwords:
            w_stp.update([word])
        else:
            wo_stp.update([word])
```

add more punctuation as needed.

**EXPLANATION**:

While processing each `word`, check if it has punctuation.  If it does, remove it.  Next, check if the entire word was a punctuation.  If it was, the length will be 0 and there is not need to further process it.  Otherwise, process the rest of the words.

**ORIGINAL SUGGESTION**

```
 def content_text(inaugural):
    inaugural = inaugural.replace(',', '').replace(';','').replace('.',''))
    (... the rest of the method...)
```

This was wrong since `inaugural` isn't a string.  @Sam noticed this error.

Comment: I'm getting an attribute error: object has no attribute 'replace', what would this mean?

Comment: @Sam that meant `inaugural` isn't a string.  i've update the answer with what i think is now correct.  i'll type up the explanation now.

Answer (score 1):

A great way to accomplish this is using a RegEx:

```
import re    
re.sub('[^A-Za-z0-9]+', ' ', nltk.corpus.inaugural.words(**replace with speeches**))
```

That will remove all characters that aren't words or numbers.

Comment: Two thoughts: #1 - Why keep numbers? #2 - Shouldn't you replace the punctuation with spaces? Seems like if you replace them with nothing, you'll just end up with a single long string of alphabetical characters and numbers and no way of identifying where one word starts and another ends, which I think is something this person wants to be able to do afterwards.

Comment: Numbers may be used within the speech, like "30 years ago" or the like.  For the second point, you are correct - I edited the regex in my post to reflect this.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare I would think that you should NOT replace punctuation with space.  punctuation is usually followed by a space unless at the end of the line.  Either way, introducing extra space is probably not the best idea.

Comment: Yeah, but if you're counting words, do you want to count 30 as a word? IDK, it's up to the asker what they want.

Comment: It may be contextually important depending on the situation - at least, that was my thought process. :-) but you are correct, it's up to the asker.  It wouldn't be too difficult to re-write the regex such that it excludes numbers.

Comment: @keda - The spaces themselves will be included in the pattern. So `. ` for example would be replaced with just a single space.

Comment: @ArtOfWarfare if there are spaces there already, then removing punctuation won't name the text one long string.  if there are, then perhaps it was intended this way.  replacing punctuation with spaces changes the integrity of the original text.  now we're making assumptions and they are typically prone to error.  if we introduce new spaces into the text, they may affect future text manipulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could make use of Python's [`maketrans`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.maketrans) and [`translate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html?highlight=maketrans#string.translate) functions as follows:

```
import string

def remove_punctuation(s):
    return s.translate(str.maketrans(string.punctuation, " " * len(string.punctuation))).replace("  ", " ")

print(remove_punctuation("Test@this!!out"))
```

This would display the following:

```
Test this out
```